# Flot graph not appearing. No error codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have been trying to make a graph plot with flot, and have ran into a problem. I am using developer tools to see where errors are, and JSlint to check my javascript, but both say there's no 'errors'. Aside from that the graph isn't showing so I must have done something wrong. Below is the graph code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var graphdata = {"label":"MMR Over time","data":{"Rubick":6524,"Lion":6550,"Magnus":6565,"Keeper of the Light":6566}};
            var options = {
                series: {
                    lines: { show: true },
                    points: {
                        radius: 3,
                        show: true
                    }
                }
            };

        $.plot($(".graph_holder"), 
                graphdata, 
                      options);
        });
```

Comment: How do you expect the graph to look like? if you want a line graph then the data should be in array format with x value being numerical, not a string. iirc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-read the flot api section on [Data Format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format).

```
"data":{"Rubick":6524,"Lion":6550,"Magnus":6565,"Keeper of the Light":6566}
```

is not valid.  The data should be in the form of an array of arrays:

```
"data": [[0,6524],[1,6550],[2,6565]] //etc...
```

If you are using the [categories](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html) plugin, you data is almost correct, but it would be:

```
"data":[["Rubick",6524],["Lion",6550],["Magnus",6565],["Keeper of the Light",6566]]
```

And of course, if you are using that plugin you need to enable it with:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "categories"
}
```